# Is it possible to use listening socket for initiating client connection?

Tags: linux, networking

Today I noticed such a situation:

```
[root@cwf-hmaster.staging-scp ~]#netstat -taupen | grep 54310
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.12.209:54310    ::ffff:10.0.12.209:54310    TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
```

You can notice that source socket is same as destination socket. Is it possible ? Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TCP connections are usually established by using a listening socket. But this is not a requirement. The TCP standard allows for both ends to send a SYN packet without any of them going through the LISTEN state.

During such a connection establishment, each peer will send a SYN and an ACK as two separate packets. So by the time they reach ESTABLISHED state there will have been sent four packets (not the usual three packets).

This is the path from CLOSED to SYN SENT to SYN RECEIVED to ESTABLISHED in the [state diagram](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-23).

A side effect of this is that it also works when a TCP endpoint connects to itself. It is rarely useful but permitted by the standard. A socket established this way will return all data it sends back to itself. You can test it with: `nc -p 12345 ::1 12345`

You'll notice that the state diagram also permits a transition from LISTEN to SYN SENT. So the standard does allow for a listening socket to be used to initiate a client connection. I do not know if Linux has implemented support for that particular sequence, the `nc` command does not appear to support it, so it would probably take a bit of coding to test.